# Overwrite userlocation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

i am building an app for demonstration at a innovation-event. In this app, there is a map and the classic blue dot is showing where we are. Because this is just a demonstration/demo app, i need to simulate that our location changes, so the blue dot moves around.

I know this is possible if you connect the phone to xcode, but i need this function to be standalone in the app, without the requirement of a mac.

So i have searched for a long time now, how to overwrite a users location, and i can't seem to find an answer. Hope you guys can help me, i am building the app in Swift btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the location with public API. (Not sure about private API if you are not planing to release to Appstore, though.)

Your best option is to introduce your own blue dot and attach it as custom pin. Then move around the pin .,.